# R, lavaan package, latent change model: Definition of change parameter?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, pre-post-comparison

I'm currently struggling with the latent change model that I try to realize in R with the lavaan package. R can't estimate all standard errors, which makes me believe that the model is not fully identified.
I did not have identification problems with the latent state model, so I guess the critical part may be due to the change parameter.

```
      Latent_change_prepost <- '
                 # first order latent variable definition
                      T1_43_1 =~ 1*A43_1_1 
                               + 1*A43_1_2 
                               + 1*A43_1_3 
                               + 1*A43_1_4 
                               + 1*A43_1_5 

                      T1_43_2 =~ 1*A43_2_1 
                               + 1*A43_2_2 
                               + 1*A43_2_3 
                               + 1*A43_2_4 
                               + 1*A43_2_5 

                      T1_43_7 =~ 1*A43_7_1 
                               + 1*A43_7_2 
                               + 1*A43_7_3 
                               + 1*A43_7_4 
                               + 1*A43_7_5 

                      T1_43_3 =~ 1*A43_3_1 
                               + 1*A43_3_2 
                               + 1*A43_3_3 
                               + 1*A43_3_4 

                      T1_43_4 =~ 1*A43_4_1 
                               + 1*A43_4_2 
                               + 1*A43_4_3 
                               + 1*A43_4_4 

                      T1_43_5 =~ 1*A43_5_1 
                               + 1*A43_5_2 
                               + 1*A43_5_3 


                  # second order latent variable definition
                      T1 =~ 1*T1_43_1
                          + 1*T1_43_2
                          + 1*T1_43_7

                      T2 =~ 1*T1_43_3
                          + 1*T1_43_4
                          + 1*T1_43_5

                  # regressions
                      change =~ 1*T2 #(no regression, need to introduce "change")
                      T2 ~ 1*T1

                  # (co)variances
                      change ~~ T1
                      T2 ~~ 0*T2

                  # intercepts
                      T1 ~ NA*1
                      T2 ~ NA*1
                      change ~ NA*1
                      T1_43_1 ~ NA*1
                      T1_43_2 ~ NA*1
                      T1_43_7 ~ NA*1
                      T1_43_3 ~ NA*1
                      T1_43_5 ~ NA*1
                    '

  fit2_latent_change <- sem(
                            model = Latent_change_prepost
                          , data = diss_prepost_w_interv_kovar
                          , missing = "fiml"
                          , meanstructure = TRUE
                          )
```

I get estimates of most parameters, but no std. errors. Also if I alternate the model slightly I might get std. errors but they are astronomically high.

Any ideas and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If this is mostly about programming you might be better off at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would think that this is an identification problem. That's why I postet it here.

Comment: I don't understand the model. Can you explain what you're trying to do a little more? Or perhaps post a path diagram?